# How can I add a console log to this const? (Using React and Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm just wondering how I could add a console.log to this const. I'd like to make the count value dynamic.

```
export const customRow = (
  row: Partial<CustomComp>
): Partial<CustomComp> => ({
  ...row,
  count: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const customRow = (
  row: Partial<CustomComp>
  ): Partial<CustomComp> => {
   console.log('something')
   return {
    ...row,
    count: 1,
  }};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add a `console.log` when the function runs?

If so, then you'll need to declare that function body with `{}` so you can have multiple statements in it.

```
export const customRow = (
  row: Partial<CustomComp>
): Partial<CustomComp> => {
  console.log('testing 123')
  return {
    ...row,
    count: 1,
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I was just confused by the syntax of this, but that is exactly what I was missing.